# SQL: I need to return all record when 'showall' is found in a parameter but when not found it needs to filter from that parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
@Network = 'showall,A,B,C' or @Network = 'A,B,C'
```

When `'showall'` is present i need to show all records but if not found i need to filter records to what is in the list.

```
WHERE rolename  in ('A','B','C')
```

I have been able to do the last part as such

```
SET @Network = '''' + replace(@Network, ',',''',''') + '''';
where rolename in (@Network);`
```

Comment: That isn't how _dynamic SQL_ works. You would need to assemble an entire statement and then `execute` it. Far better to use one of the answers provided. You may also want to consider making the un-value `NULL` mean "no filter" rather than `'showall'` occurring somewhere in the string. Allowing both filtering and not filtering at once is a questionable design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
where @network in (select s.value from string_split(@network, ',') s) or
      concat(',', @network, ',') like '%,showall%,'
```

Answer (score 0):

`IN` doesn't work like that, `WHERE rolename IN ('A,B,C')` would be equivalent to `WHERE rolename = 'A,B,C'`. `IN` takes a list of scalar values (e.g. `'A','B','C'`), not a delimited scalar value (e.g. `'A,B,C'`).

*Assuming* you're using a modern version of SQL Server, then you would need to use `STRING_SPLIT` to work with a delimited scalar valueL

```
WHERE rolename IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Network,','))
```

If, however, you want to pass a "show all" parameter, then *normally* you're better off passing `NULL`:

```
WHERE (rolename IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Network,','))
   OR  @Network IS NULL)
```

If you must pass `'showall'` make that the value of `@Network`, not `'showall,A,B,C'`, and then just replace `@Network IS NULL` with `@Network = 'showall'`

Note that with queries like this, you are likely to suffer poor query plan caching. If you query is as simple as the above `WHERE` clauses, then simply adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` will get around this; as it forces the data engine to recreate the query plan each time. If you're query is more complex, however, then you would actually be better off going down a dynamic query route, and only including the `rolename IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Network,',')` clause when needed.

Comment: you missed that my SET command changed the IN to look like this WHERE rolename in ('A','B','C') - I had a typo and the work network there and fixed it. Probably why you were confused.

Comment: @DougMoore no, I didn't, `@Network` is *still* a scalar variable. That effective changed the **`varchar`** value from `'A,B,C'` to `'A','B','C'`. Which, if written would be `SET @Network = '''A'',''B'',''C'''`. No matter how many single quotes you wrap around the values in a delimited **scalar** value it is *still* a **scalar** value.

Comment: If you don't believe me, check this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90bd0dc720b7f630fde611f2fef5bf2a)